# Bash Conditional Quote in String

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-statements

I have a CSV file that I'm parsing in bash that, for one column, has more than one value for some rows.
For example, a line with multiple values may look like

```
name,12,120,east,"sw1,sw2,sw3"
```

But not all rows have it. Some may look like

```
name,10,141,west,sw5534a
```

What I'm trying to do is if that column has quotes in it to remove them and set the variable to just `sw1,sw2,sw3`

Relevant parts of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=file.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read name building id region parents
do
echo "
....snip....
parents $parents"
```

The output I want for $parents should be `sw1,sw2,sw3` but right now it spits out as `"sw1,sw2,sw3"`
I've tried messing around with regex matching in a conditional if the column has a comma to remove the first and last two characters, but I couldn't get it to work. Either it would remove the first `s` and the last `3` or it would just error out.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: can you not just do: sed 's/"//g' file.csv

Comment: Can any other fields in the file be quoted like this?

Comment: @Barmar: I disagree with your marking this question as a duplicate. That other question is about awk, not bash.

Comment: It's about using `awk` to parse a CSV file in a `bash` script. I don't think you can do this properly with just `bash`.

Comment: Side issue: you can set IFS locally for the `read` statement. That avoids having to save and restore it, and also avoids any interactions it might have inside the body of the while loop: `while IFS=, read name building id region parents`. Also, you practically always want to supply the `-r` flag to `read`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove both instances of the `"` character in the `$parents` variable with substring replacement:

```
echo ${parents//\"/}
```

This replaces all `"` characters with the empty string.

Comment: How does that help? The idea is to treat that as one field because it's quoted.

Comment: Works great! Thanks heaps! (Won't let me accept your answer for another 3 minutes, but I will at that point)

Comment: @Barmar: read the question. He wants the double quote characters in the field value removed using bash constructs. My code does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, misread, I thought you were removing them from the line before reading it.

Comment: Although if there are any other fields in the CSV that have commas in them, the `read` statement will put the wrong fields in `parents`.

Comment: And as always, if the string contains runs of whitespace or shell wildcards, not quoting it properly will mangle those.  You want `echo "${parents//\"/}"` with double quotes, and basically always use double quotes [unless you know what you are doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).

Answer (score 1):

```
parents="${parents#\"}"
parents="${parents%\"}"
```

This will remove the first character if a quote, and the last character if a quote. If they are not a quote, they will be left untouched.

Comment: Nice, but escaping required for " within { }.